# Can I use the Kinect Windows Live Messenger on a PC?

Tags: kinect, windows-live-messenger

Can I use the Kinect Windows Live Messenger on a PC? I heard rumor that it worked and it would focus on the person talking.

If this is the wrong place to ask this which "StackExchange" should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for some time it is looking like NO